# Do i need to remove a drywall steel stud before closing a closet space?

Tags: drywall, framing

I want to close a small closet space in one of my house's rooms. I scrapped a bit of the frame and found what looks like a metal frame (which was hidden by mud). The metal frame seems to be only a few mm thick. Do i need to strip the metal out of the frame or can i just drill it enough to reach the wood and attach my framing wood directly to it? (then throw the drywall and mud on top for the finish)

Thanks

Comment: It sounds like drywall corner bead, a thin metal piece made to protect drywall corner.  Pictures will help.

Comment: How about [edit]ing your post and including a picture of the overall situation and a nice, clear, well lit, focused picture of the metal you've found.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what and how you frame.

Those "metal" strips (corner protection) for the drywall, might or might not be in your way.

They are easy to drill through if that is what you want.

However they might interfere with hight (flush fit) of your framing to the drywall, in which case you remove them.